# Get list of users & persons by login with ldap java

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I'm currently working on a app that contains official employees information even the login.

I would like to do an LDAP search filter that retrieve for me all the information concerning specific users that corresspond to a list of logins I provide.

A bit like a select statement in sql : `select * from ldap where login in(my list of login)`

I'm using the basic javax.naming.directory with all the blah blah comming with.

```
// set properties for our connection and provider
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
  "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory" );
properties.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://myserver.somewhere.com:389"; );
properties.put( Context.REFERRAL, "ignore" );

// set properties for authentication
properties.put( Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "User Name" );
properties.put( Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password" );

InitialDirContext context = new InitialDirContext( properties );
```

The only thing I could do so far is lising all the object users if I could get directly those I'm looking for that could be very nice :)

Thanks a lot for your help guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the final query in the search filter I had to put is :

```
(&(objectCategory=person)
    (|
        (sAMAccountName=login1)
        (sAMAccountName=login2)
        (sAMAccountName=login3)
    )
)
```

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: this helped me a lot. in human words: find all people identified by login1, login2, login3

Answer (score 1):

```
    String searchFilter = "your_query";
    String ldapSearchBase = "dc=ad,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
    SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
    searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = context.search(ldapSearchBase, searchFilter, searchControls);
```

an query might be like this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + accountName + "))
```

complete example here:
http://www.adamretter.org.uk/blog/entries/LDAPTest.java

Comment: So then will I have to use a StringBuilder to list all the `(sAMAccountName=" + accountName + ")`, right...?